# error: can't login on Web of Science website with python selenium webscaper

Tags: python, authentication, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to login on Web of Science: https://mjl.clarivate.com/login;createAccount=false;referrer=%2Fhome

I have to fill the "Email address" and "Password" boxes with my data, and I'm using Selenium webscaper on Python. I have tried with xpath, css_selector, and class_name, but the result remains the same: I can not automate my access on this website, because it can not find the element (xpath, css_selector, etc). (i.e. `NoSuchElementException`)

This is an example with the email and xpath

```py
xpath = "/html/body/microui-app/div/div/microui-base/div/div[1]/div/base-login/div/div[3]/div[1]/login/steam-login/form/mat-form-field[1]/div/div[1]/div/input"

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath ))).click() 

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))).send_keys(my_email)
```

I have tried for two days, also selecting other xpaths from this page (I'm not an expert, therefore I thought I kept mistaking something in the xpath (taking the wrong one)). Does anyone have some ideas about this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your login container is placed in iframe `#loginIframe`, so to access inner elements that are placed in it, you should change context to this iframe.

Also, you should close cookie consent before starting typing as far as consent would intercept click on submit button.

After clicking on sign in, you should change context to body - `default_content`.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get('https://mjl.clarivate.com/login;createAccount=false;referrer=%2Fhome')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'banner-close-button'))).click()
login_frame = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'loginIframe')))

driver.switch_to.frame(login_frame)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name=email]'))).send_keys('test@test.com')
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[type=password]').send_keys('somepass')
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[type=submit]').click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```